# Is the plot and delivery of The Walking Dead season 6 partly motivated by cost control?

Tags: the-walking-dead

It's well-known that on long-running successful shows, the salaries of key actors can cause an ultimately self-defeating situation (i.e. eventually even the most successful shows have to pay their cast so much money it becomes uneconomical -- cf. *TNG* and *Friends*).

In season 6 of *The Walking Dead*, we have a number of simultaneous plotlines playing out in separate episodes.  This means that many key characters do not appear in several episodes:

For example, the following main characters appear:

- episode 1 - all
- episode 2 - Maggie, Eugene,  Carl,  Carol, Morgan, Gabriel
- episode 3 - Rick, Michonne, Glenn, Daryl, Sasha, Abraham
- episode 4 - Morgan (and Eastman) only, well plus Tabitha
- episode 5 - Rick, Maggie, Carl
- episode 6 - Daryl, Sasha, Abraham
- episode 7 - everyone except Daryl, Sasha, and Abraham
- episode 8 - everyone except Daryl, Sasha, and Abraham

The difference is that we have a series of episodes rotating among different cast, some of them overlapping in time, in which the other characters do not appear at all.  In particular, **Rick did not appear** in three episodes, which seemed unusual to me personally.

## So, how much of this style was motivated by cost savings?

This is significantly different from the previous five seasons, where, even with just as many cast members, the episode would jump around among the cast even when they were separated, except for pehaps an episode here or there.   Here we have at leave five episodes in a row focusing on **only a small subset** of the cast.     Actors generally are paid by the episode, and only for the episodes in which they appear.

Comment: It maybe a cost issue, but it may also be the fact that at least 12 main characters. Being forced to feature them all in every episode would hamper the story telling more so than splitting it up in my opinion.

Comment: A salary can defeat itself?

Comment: It's also an excellent way to heighten tension. It allows the writers to keep us hanging with different [Uncertain Doom](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/UncertainDoom) and [Our Hero is dead](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OurHeroIsDead) tropes without getting too cheesy

Comment: @Rigas, that may be, but everyone is missing the point that the other five seasons *weren't like this* except for an episode here or there perhaps.

Comment: Come on,  @Praxis, show me the evidence and stick it to the downvoters.  :)

Comment: @Rigas, Even when there were just as many characters and they were separated, it would normally jump around within the episode.   Whereas,  I believe actors are paid by the episode for episodes in which they appear.

Comment: Oh yay!   It's the good ole downvote bandwagon.    Disagreement with the premise is not a reason to downvote; it's a reason to answer in the negative.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : I'm here (and I clicked the up button).  ;-)  I'll do some research.

Comment: +1 - Interesting question, and something I had noticed as well (though never thought much of it).

Comment: The second part of the season 4,  where the group was split into small groups of two or three people looking for Terminus, show that it is not new.

Comment: I downvoted, since I cannot see how it could be answered.

Comment: @Taladris:  This might be a good point, but if it occurred in season 4, it doesn't mean the same motivation wasn't present there.   Regarding whether it can be answered:  of course it can -- there can be a comment from the producers.   Especially with as much discussion goes around for *TWD* and the existence of *Talking Dead*, it is all the more likely than for other shows.    Even if the answer is 'not that we know of so far' this is an answer.

Comment: It should be considered that even ignoring the cost of actor salaries, AMC is a cheapskate channel. They ran off Darabont for this reason... apparently they wanted him to show zombies offscreen because it was cheaper to play back growling sounds than to do the practical effects, things of that nature. They wanted to limit the large swarms of zombies to "8 or fewer" even in key scenes. They want the esteem that comes with having a hit show, but they don't like the price tag and never have. So, @Taladris, yes, there's plenty of evidence that would allow this to be answered.

Comment: @ThePopMachine: I was just commenting to say that the premise that it hasn't been done in the show before is wrong. Knowing that the show producers have been cheap from the beginning does not really help to answer the question (the answers so far are "maybe" and gossips), so I'll maintain my downvote for now.

Comment: @Taladris:   You are entitled.   I just question whether "is answerable" is the right metric, particularly because it is proven over and over again that many questions are only "unanswerable" until they are suddenly answered.   And the content of the *answers* should not be what affects votes on *questions*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Maybe

It's true, actors in US television are paid per episode, not per season.

So, it is conceivable that actors may not be scheduled to appear in every episode of Season 6 as a means of lowering episode costs.

According to [this](http://www.monkeysfightingrobots.com/the-walking-dead-showrunner-confirms-the-fate-of-ricks-hand/) article regarding Rick's hand,

> The series has previously stated that the special effects needed would be too expensive to have the lead character lose a hand.

Certainly, costs are a concern at this point.  Whether or not actors' salaries are preventing them from having the special effects they want, and whether or not actors' salaries are preventing them from having the entire cast appear in every episode, are matters of pure speculation.

It's not exactly the kind of thing the producers will wish to comment on directly at this stage, and it can always be spun as a creative decision — after the show has wrapped up and people start analyzing what could have or should have been done with *TWD*, statements of a more direct nature will be made by the producers and actors.

Comment: That's a lame answer for Rick's hand, after what they did for Hershel's leg.  Something tells me they just wanted to spotlight characters and hold off on revealing that you-know-who is still alive.

Comment: @Axelrod -- not really, Herschel was never very active, and he didn't last for very long.   It's a lot easier to deal with green screen or a buried leg when someone is planting seeds or sitting around vs. routinely killing zombies.   Plus there's the issue of raw screen time.

Comment: @ThePopMachine My only point was that it was very cheaply done. The effect would be the same as if Rick started wearing a jacket and just kept his hand (with some bandage tape on the end) in his sleeve.

Comment: @Axelrod:   That wouldn't be very convincing and it would be viewed as lowering the production quality.

Answer (score 4):

Apologies for the link, but these would all be gossip/entertainment sites anyway:

http://www.vulture.com/2011/08/walking_dead_frank_darabont_1.html

> The Walking Dead is AMC's biggest show, but it's also expensive.
>   According to THR, the network slashed episode budgets from $3.4
>   million to $2.75 million for the second season, and execs asked
>   Darabont to move more episodes indoors and keep zombies off-screen to
>   save on makeup costs. Darabont, who is himself an expensive talent
>   from the feature-film world, refused to cut corners.

Cost is *always* an issue with a television show, but in the case of *The Walking Dead* it has been a problem since the beginning.

AMC is willing to do nearly anything (except let this show be gobbled up by another network) to be as miserly as possible. Including nuking the talent that made it such a hit that first season.

This has not changed to any great degree since. Costs have only gone up (despite any measures taken).

While it's impossible at this point in time to answer whether season 6 is specifically driven by cost control, in general this is true and your hypothesis can't be ruled out. If writers were to come out with the truth (that plot devices were kaboshed, that shooting locations were ruled out, etc) they'd probably be fired. So don't expect many details any time soon.